# Why does my CSS / Layout change after AJAX / JavaScript did run?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

On user click i run an AJAX call to fetch data from a third party API. Before the action the frontend/layout is rendered correctly, but after the data was fetched and populated to the frontend, the layout changes.

After debugging several times it seems that the inherited relation changes.

What could be an issue / why is that?

**This is the affected HTML part:**

```css
#mainContent .fourthRow .Goals {
  float: left;
  width: 20%;
  height: 280px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  background-color: #F2F8FF;
}

#mainContent .fourthRow .goalsColumn {
  background-color: #F2F8FF;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  height: 100%;
  width: 24.3%;
  text-align: center;
  border-right: 1px solid;
  margin-right: 1px;
  border-color: #DADADA;
  font-family: 'Muli', sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 15px;
}

#mainContent .fourthRow .goalsColumn p {
  height: 40px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid;
  border-color: #DADADA;
  font-family: 'Muli', sans-serif;
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="fourthRow">
    <div class="Goals">
      <div class="goalsColumn">
        <div id="divGoal"><img id="goal" src="{% static "images/goal.png" %}" alt="soccergoal"></div>
        <div><p>Scored Goals</p></div>
        <div><p>SGPM</p></div>
        <div><p>Conceded Goals</p></div>
        <div><p>CGPM</p></div>
        <div><p>Goals Total</p></div>
        <div><p>GTPM</p></div>
      </div>
      <div class="goalsColumn">
        <div><p>Home</p></div>
        <div id="goals_home_for" "goals_style"><p></p></div>
        <div id="goalsAvg_home_for"><p></p></div>
        <div id="goals_home_against"><p></p></div>
        <div id="goalsAvg_home_against"><p></p></div>
        <div id="goals_total_home"><p></p></div>
        <div id="goalsAvg_home_total"><p></p></div>
      </div>
      <div class="goalsColumn">
        <div><p>Away</p></div>
        <div id="goals_away_for"><p></p></div>
        <div id="goalsAvg_away_for"><p></p></div>
        <div id="goals_away_against"><p></p></div>
        <div id="goalsAvg_away_against"><p></p></div>
        <div id="goals_total_away"><p></p></div>
        <div id="goalsAvg_away_total"><p></p></div>
      </div>
      <div class="goalsColumn">
        <div><p>Total</p></div>
        <div id="goals_total_for2"><p></p></div>
        <div id="goalsAvg_total_for"><p></p></div>
        <div id="goals_total_against"><p></p></div>
        <div id="goalsAvg_total_against"><p></p></div>
        <div id="goals_total"><p></p></div>
        <div id="goalsAvg_total"><p></p></div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

**Correct before JS/AJAX run:**

[image]

**Messed up after JS/AJAX run:**

[image]

Comment: Because the HTML changed. The style rule you're alluding to is applying to the `<p>` element, which is no longer present in the second image. It would seem as though in your AJAX callback, you're not wrapping the text in a `<p>`. Without seeing this code though, we can only tell you what's wrong, we cannot provide an adequate solution.

Comment: This is a snippage of the JS: `goals_total = goals_total_for + goals_total_against;
      $("#goals_total").html(goals_total);
    goals_total_home = goals_home_for + goals_home_against;
      $("#goals_total_home").html(goals_total_home);
    goals_total_away = goals_away_for + goals_away_against;
      $("#goals_total_away").html(goals_total_away);`

Comment: I have no idea what those variables represent. Please include the javascript *in the question itself*, rather than in a comment. Your code shouldn't be setting the `.html()` to a value; it should be setting the html to a `<p>` that contains the value. `$("#goals_total_home").html(\`<p>${goals_total_home}</p>\`)`, for example.

Comment: So the main part I ****ed up is that I removed the <p> tags by populating the data to my html since I didn't insert them in the backend. Thank you!

Comment: Can't edit main post since a mod edited it and now it has some weird errors. But i solved my initial issue. Thank you so much. Beerish greets from Germany

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before ajax request `div#goals_home_for` has a `p` tag inside it. And the `p` tag's style has `height: 40px`, so `div#goals_home_for` has 40px height. But after ajax request maybe your javascript edits DOM from response json data, and `div#goals_home_for` loses its child `p` tag. And it also loses its height.
Long story short, try:

```
#mainContent .fourthRow #goals_home_for {
   height: 40px;
   <!-- Rest is omitted -->
}
```

or edit your javascript so that it wraps `p` tags around each data.

Comment: Thanks for your insight. I would like to avoid this solution though since I have dozens of IDs which I would have to mention, wouldn't I?

Comment: Of course, it's just one of many workarounds. I think changing javascript code is more reasonable. But you didn't provide your javascript code, so all I have to do was to suggest css change. And btw, your html is malformed, such as `<div id="goals_home_for" "goals_style">`.

Comment: Ya the second ID was just an attempt to solve the above issue ;)

Comment: @Phanti, you can't have multiple ids for a single html tag. ids are meant to be unique. The malformed html doesn't *attempt* to solve the problem; it is a problem.